# Application of Riemann Roch

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, complex-geometry

I have read that thanks to Riemann Roch theorem, if get $\Sigma$ a compact Riemann Surface of genus $g$ there exists a conformal branch covering $\phi: \Sigma \rightarrow S^2$ of degree less than $g+1$. Unfortunately I have found only very abstract references which not clearly implies this fact. does any one can explain this to me? Ideally with a basic reference.

Comment: When a reference is abstract is probably dependent on who you are, but the result you're mentioning is Corollary 16.12 of Forster's book "Lectures on Riemann Surfaces" which is fairly concrete.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $D$ be a finite collection of $d$ points on $\Sigma$.  The RR theorem shows
that the vector space of meromorphic functions on $\Sigma$ with at worst a simple pole at each $D$ has dimension $\geq d + 1 - g$, which is $> 1$ if $d > g$.  Thus (choosing any $D$ with $d  > g$) this space contains a non-constant meromorphic
function $f$. (The constant functions contribute just one dimension.) Since $f$ has at most $d$ *simple* poles, it induces a degree $\leq d$ branched covering $\Sigma \to \mathbb C P^1$.